# Different view of inverse trigonometry.

Tags: trigonometry, inverse

If
$$\tan\theta =x $$
$$\theta=\frac{x}{tan(1)}$$
$$\theta=\frac{x}{\dfrac{\pi}4}$$
$$\pi\theta=4x$$
Is this valid?

I am learning inverse trigonometry but always my mind goes to these situations. So can somebody explain what limitations are there in inverse trigonometry functions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the real numbers, the notation $a^{-1}$ means "multiplicative inverse" (i.e., "division".)  In trigonometry, the notation $\tan^{-1}x$ doesn't not mean "multiplicative inverse."  So the place where you try to divide both sides by $\tan$ doesn't work. Just as, in algebra, you computed inverse functions (using the notation $f^{-1}$), in trig, $\tan^{-1}$ is the inverse *function*, not the inverse of multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

Your second step is completely wrong. You cant arrive from $\tan\theta =x$ to $\theta=\frac{x}{tan(1)}$. What you can get is If $\tan\theta =x$ then, $\theta=tan^{-1}(x)$